# Independent vectors in the permuting coordinates action of $S_n$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with equation $\sum_i x_i=0$. The symmetric group $S_n$ acts on $V$ by $s\cdot (v_1,\ldots,v_n)=(v_{s^{-1}(1)},\ldots,v_{s^{-1}(n)})$. Consider those $v\in V$ with the following property:

> For any $n-1$ elements $s_1=\text{id},s_2,\ldots,s_{n-1}\in S_n$, the vectors
> $v,s_2\cdot v,\ldots,s_{n-1}\cdot v$ are *independent*.

**Question**: what $v$ have this property?

Some simple observations:

1. If $H_{ij}$, for $1\leq i<j\leq n$, is the hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with equation $x_i-x_j=0$ (i.e. a reflecting hyperplane of $S_n$ in the permuting coordinates action on $\mathbb{R}^n$) then a $v$ with the property above cannot lie in $V\cap H_{ij}$.
2. If $X$ is a proper non-empty subset of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $H_X$ is the hyperplane with equation $\sum_{i\in X}x_i=0$ then a $v$ with the property above cannot lie in $V\cap H_X$.
3. When $n=3$ the $v\in V$ that remain after removing those in (1) and (2) satisfy the property above.

Comment: Suppose you have $n-1$ elements stabilizing two points. Then the vectors $v, s_2v \dots, s_{n-1}v$ all have two coordinates identical, so they lie in a hyperplane of $V$. Hence we must have $|S_{n-2}| = (n-2)! < n - 1$, so $n \leq 4$.

Comment: A trivial note:  there's no need to require $s_1 = 1$ in your collection of $n - 1$ elements, since the set of $v$ with your property is stable under $S_n$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Yes, good point!

Answer (score 5):

This is **not** an answer, but I think comments can't include images.  I have marked it as CW to avoid reputation for a non-answer.  (Actually I think @SeanEberhard's emendations below, describing the forbidden surfaces algebraically, now makes this probably as good an answer as is likely to arise.)

Per your answer for $n = 3$ and @SeanEberhard's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391228/independent-vectors-in-the-permuting-coordinates-action-of-s-n-on-mathbbr#comment997560_391228), we need only consider $n = 4$.

In the ‘obvious’ coördinates $(a, b, c)$ on $V$ (i.e., writing a typical element of $V$ as $(a, b, c, -(a + b + c))$), here is the picture, generated by *extremely* naïve Mathematica code, of the region that *doesn't* satisfy your condition.

[image: The region being considered when n = 4]

```
Region[ImplicitRegion[
  Or @@
   (# == 0 & /@
     (Det /@ ((Most /@ # &) /@
         (Prepend[#, {a, b, c, -(a + b + c)}] & /@
           Select[
            Tuples[
             Select[Permutations[{a, b, c, -(a + b + c)}], 
              Not[# === {a, b, c, -(a + b + c)}] &],
             2],
            Not[#[[1]] === #[[2]]] &])))),
  {a, b, c}]]
```

Computer says it is the union of the following surfaces, together with all permutations of $(a, b, c, -(a+b+c))$ (corresponding $s_2, s_3$ also listed):
$$
a = 0 \qquad [(3,4), (2,3,4)],\\
b - c = 0 \qquad [(1,3)(2,4), (1,2,4,3)],\\
b + c = 0 \qquad [(1,2), (1,4)(2,3)],\\
b^{2} - a c = 0 \qquad [(3,4), (1,2,3,4)],\\
a^{2} - a b + b^{2} - a c - b c + c^{2} = 0 \qquad [(1,3,2), (1,2,3)],\\
a^{3} + a^{2} b + a b^{2} + b^{3} - a b c - a c^{2} - b c^{2} - c^{3} = 0 \qquad [(1,4,3,2), (1,2,3)],\\
a^{2} + a b + b^{2} + a c + 3 b c + c^{2} = 0 \qquad [(1,3)(2,4), (1,3,4)],\\
2 a^{2} + 2 a b + b^{2} + 2 a c + c^{2} = 0 \qquad [(1,3,4,2), (1,2,4,3)],\\
2 a^{2} b + 2 a b^{2} - a^{2} c + a b c - b^{2} c - a c^{2} - b c^{2} - c^{3} = 0 \qquad [(1,4,3), (1,2,3)].
$$

Comment: It looks beautiful but I'm struggling to understand what it is telling me about the problem.

Comment: @MarkWildon, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391228/independent-vectors-in-the-permuting-coordinates-action-of-s-n-on-mathbbr/391236#comment997614_391236), nothing, probably.  This is very much not an answer.  I just wanted to see if I could see anything in the picture, and, since I made it, I thought I'd share it with others.

Comment: Not much more to say. It's the union of some surfaces, including OP's $a = 0$, $a + b = 0$, $a - b = 0$ as well as $a^2 - bc = 0$ and a few others.

Comment: @SeanEberhard, a [few](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391228/independent-vectors-in-the-permuting-coordinates-action-of-s-n-on-mathbbr/391236#comment997912_391236)?

Comment: @LSpice I wrote them down.

Comment: @SeanEberhard, [thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391228/independent-vectors-in-the-permuting-coordinates-action-of-s-n-on-mathbbr/391236#comment997945_391236)! I knew symmetry considerations would cut down somewhat, but I was sure it couldn't be that much. Could you say which tuples $(s_1, s_2, s_3)$ give rise to which surfaces?

Comment: My computer also gave up that information after some further torture

Comment: [Thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391228/independent-vectors-in-the-permuting-coordinates-action-of-s-n-on-mathbbr/391236#comment998076_391236)!

Comment: @LSpice This is useful to know (and nice picture).